# How to save game on Kinect Stars Wars?

Tags: kinect-star-wars

My son is seven, and we created a profile that is recognized by facial recognition.  We do not have an Xbox Live account.

All I want is for him to not have to start at the beginning of the game every time he wants to play.

How do we save progress?

Comment: Does the game manual in the case not say?

Comment: "We do not have an Xbox Live account." There is your problem. Why not? It's free! I don't believe you can save a game if you are not playing with an account. Besides, the game autosaves its checkpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Try first by learning to pause the game. Depending on the game it can be anything from throwing your hands in the air to just walking out of the room. Occasionally it will bring up a pause screen and there should be a "Save and Quit" or "Save Game".

[You aren't the Only One with an issue](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997652-kinect-star-wars/62470362) and that link states that the campaign runs through a checkpoint system. Usually after the cutscene is when these pop. Also make sure your son is choosing "Continue" instead of "New Game"